# Can anyone help me here in string strip method in python?

Tags: python

string = "xoxo love xoxo"

print(string.strip("xoe"))  # -> Without space befor x Output will be love

print(string.strip(" xoe"))  # -> With space before x Output will be lov

Why when i put a space before the letter (x) in the example it removes the letter (e) from the word (love) and when i do not put the space it does not remove anything ?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHeUX.png

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Consider what strip() does:

`strip("xoe")` looks from left and right and starts stripping an `'x'` or `'o'` or `'e'`. When it encounters the space, it stops stripping so the `'e'` will not be stripped.

`strip(" xoe")` does the same, but when it encounters the space, it strips the space and after that it strips the `'e'` also.